# Why sometimes string values are not available in the Xcode debugger?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ios

Why sometimes the value of string variables is not available in the debugger when debugging an iPhone app in Xcode?

The mouse over the variable gives:

```
{(unichar *)Xcode_CFStringSummary($VAR, $ID)}:s
```

Printing the description to the console gives:

```
Unable to access variable "myVariable"
```

This doesn't always happen. Why?

Comment: Do you have Debug configuration enabled with symbols and without optimization? The variable might have been optimized away...